# why many methods marked as obsolete

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wonder why many of the c#-driver-methods (most user and collection-methods) are marked as obsolete. Instead we should use the CommandDocument with dynamic BsonDocuments.

I would highly appreciate if there would be wrapper-classes in future inside the c#-driver.

one example.

If I want to create a user I have to write this code

```
        var userCommand = new CommandDocument
        {
            { "createUser", username },
            { "pwd", securePassword.ToString() },
            { "digestPassword", false },
            { "roles", new BsonArray()}
        };

        var result = _database.RunCommand(userCommand);
```

instead of just

```
        _db.addUser(username, password);
```

Of course I can build my own wrapper-classes but I would like to know why all this classes are obsolete. Maybe someone can explain it to me. :)

thanks
Tobias

Comment: This change is likely due to a change in how authentication and user setup is handled, that occurred when MongoDB 2.4 was introduced. In 2.2 there were only read and readWrite roles. Note that the 2.2 format is preserved for backwards compatibility and the deprecated method works with the old definitions. The following page lists the new roles in 2.4: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/

Comment: so to use the CommandDocument like I did is the way to go?

Comment: Correct - from the C# driver a "createUser" command is the way to add users. A full list of user management commands is available here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/#user-management-commands